# Can my iPhone interact with HomeKit Accessory Simulator for MACOSX?

Tags: iphone, xcode, simulator, homekit, ios-homekit

Can my physical iPhone interact with HomeKit Accessory Simulator for MACOSX?
Unfortunately, Now, I'm able to use HomeKit Accessory Simulator only with the iPhone Simulator, not with the real,physical phone! 
Is there a way to do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the HomeKit Accessory Simulator to show accessories on your physical device, you need to have your computer and phone on the same WiFi network. Once you've done that, using your HMAccessoryBrowser will see any unpaired accessories.